# Android - Can I see if WRITE_SETTINGS permission granted API < 23

Tags: android, permissions, target

I have an app that needs to support minSdkVersion lower than 23.
Recently Google requires all apps have targetSdkVersion 26+

Now we must request `Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` with `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS`.

However I am unable to determine if permission is granted without using `Settings.System.canWrite(context);` *(canWrite() requires minSdkVersion >= 23 )*

I've tried

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
```

and

`PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(getCurrentActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)`

both do not return `PERMISSION_GRANTED` even when the permission is granted. (checked with `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS` activity slider is ON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no runtime permissions for API<23. So the user already granted the permission as a stipulation for downloading the app.